# RXjs: reset true value after period of time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have such service/state:

```
export class SpinnerService {
  public throttleTime: number = 10;
  public isLoading$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() {}

  public showLoader(): void {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);
  }

  public hideLoader(): void {
    this.isLoading$.next(false);
  }

  public get isLoadingAPIVal$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoading$.pipe(throttleTime(this.throttleTime), shareReplay());
  }
}
```

Basically - here I store & get if I need to show app loading animation. I can set this value in multiple components in the same time or with any delays. For example I set isLoading$ to true in one component, and after 0.004sec in another.  And everything works fine. Except one case.

Sometimes I need to set isLoading$ to false after it's last true value was set > 20 seconds from now.

How can I reset it to false after it was set to true last time and after 20sec?

I tried so:

```
  constructor() {
    this.isLoading$
      .pipe(
        filter((val) => !!val),
        timeout(20000),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
      });
  }
```

but looks that it's not working and it takes first true value.

Comment: I think you need to clarify a little bit. Are you saying you set the value to `false` and then some other component set it to `true`? 

Also, using `subscribe` like this to feed into a stream seems kind of counter intuitive. You should subscribe in your templates instead and set the values where they belong.

Comment: @DanielB it's a generic service - I can't set it everywhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is:

```js
public get isLoadingAPIVal$(): Observable<boolean> {
  return merge(
    this.isLoading$,
    this.isLoading$.pipe(
      debounceTime(20000),
      map(() => false),
    ),
  ).pipe(
    throttleTime(this.throttleTime),
    shareReplay(),
  );
}
```

What it does is:

1. debounce the signals from `isLoading$`, to get a new signal 20 seconds after `isLoading$` last emitted anything:

   ```
   this.isLoading$.pipe(
     debounceTime(20000),
   ```
2. emit `false` values then:

   ```
   map(() => false),
   ```
3. merge your original stream of signals, and the final debounced "false" answer 20 seconds later together :)

   ```
   merge(
     this.isLoading$,
     this.isLoading$.pipe(
       debounceTime(20000),
       map(() => false),
     ),
   )
   ```

Comment: throttleTime is gone :) i need it... to avoid flickering when false & true are set with tiny time offset...

Comment: also I think shareReplay is in wrong place :

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry about these, I didn't pay close enough attention to the rest of your code! I fixed it in mine.